# How to represent a question in algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

Please could someone show me how to represent this pub quiz question in algebra?

> A Gym has $12$kg weights and $14$kg weights.
>
> If it has $78$ weights in total and the total weight of the $12$kg weights is the same as the total weight of those weighing $14$kg, what is the total weight of them?

Thanks

Comment: Try denoting the number of $12$kg weights with $a$ and the number of $14$kg weights with $b$, can you set up the equations now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set $t = $ number of $12$kg weights, and $f =$ number of $14$kg weights.

Then we can say that $$t+f=78$$ from the fact that there are $78$ weights in total.

We can also say that $$12t=14f$$ from the fact that the total weight of the $12$kg weights is equal to the total weight of the $14$kg weights.

We then have two simultaneous equations in two variables which we can solve easily:

\begin{align}12t&=14f\\
t&=\frac76f\\
&\Downarrow\\
\frac 76f+f&=78\\
\frac{13}{6}f&=78\\
f&=36\\
&\Downarrow\\
t+36&=78\\
t&=42\end{align}

So, we have $42$ weights weighing $12$kg and $36$ weights weighing $14$kg.

Answer (score 1):

$12x=14y$
$x+y=78$

$x$= no. of weights of 12 kg
$y$=no. of wieghts of 14 kg